# Dataflow pipeline to load whole GCS plain text file contents, path and created time into a PubSub json formatted message

Tags: java, python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a very specific requirement of reading some hundreds of millions of plain text files from a GCS bucket into Cloud PubSub using Cloud Dataflow. I need the whole contents of the file to be in a single message, but the only examples I could find only read files line by line, like CSV or JSON.

Besides this, there are other requirements that proven to be even more difficult to find a solution for. The pubsub message should also contain the complete path of the GCS object and the "created time" of the GCS object. The PubSub message format should be similar to this:

```
{
    "gcsCreatedTime": "Apr 1, 2021, 12:34:21 PM",
    "gcsPath": "gs://bucketName/xxx/yyy/zzz/file.xml",
    "fileStringContent": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Whatever solution provided can be in java or python. It doesn't matter, as long as it works.

Also, streaming is preferred but it can be batch.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you could check out the FileIO api (https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html). There you have access to the filename and the whole content of the file